# onda v989 allwiner a83t octa core 32gb bootloop beacause i installed chainfire 3d :( i cant fix it, please help

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, adb, rom-flashing, custom-roms

i have onda v989 allwiner a83t octa core 32gb bootloop beacause i installed chainfire 3d :( i cant fix it, please help please, i need it so much. my FBgmail: huynam371@gmail.com . plese help me!!!! text me some mess or teamviewer for helping !!!! thanks a lots ..... i dont know too much about my tablet. i cant use adb shell, i typed "adb sideload [rom.zip]" and i got at all: e footer is wrong .................

Comment: Did you try flashing the stock firmware yet?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flash the stock firmware (ROM) for your tablet, this will overwrite all modified system files. 
Since it is powered by Allwinner chip, you need a tool called [PHOENIXSUIT](https://androidmtk.com/download-phoenixsuit) (in English) or ONDASUIT (in Chinese) to flash the image file. Click this [link](http://www.ondaforum.com/files/download/435-989-air-core8-v105-20150410zip/) to get the flash file (ROM image). Don't forget to unzip first.